# Django Custom Model, Email Field disable for filling when Create User by Admin

Tags: django, django-admin

1. I changed the default User Model to my custom usermodel and use email for login.
2. After login into admin and trying to create a new user, the email field can not be filled. Like the screenshot below.
3. I deleted `db.sqlite3` while solving some other problems. But already re-build later.
4. `python manage.py createsuperuser` still works. I can create a superuser through the terminal.

[image]

Here the code

`./accounts/admin.py`

```py
from django.contrib import admin
from django.contrib.auth.admin import UserAdmin
# Register your models here.

from .models import Account

class AccountAdmin(UserAdmin):

    list_display = ('email', 'date_joined', 'last_login', 'is_admin')
    search_fields = ('email',)
    readonly_fields = ('email', 'date_joined', 'last_login')

    ordering = ('email',) # solution for E033

    filter_horizontal = ()
    list_filter = ()

    fieldsets = (
        (None, {'fields': ('email', 'password')}),
    )

    add_fieldsets = (
        (None, {
            'classes': ('wide',),
            'fields': ('email', 'password1', 'password2'),
        }),
    )
admin.site.register(Account, AccountAdmin)
```

`./accounts/backends.py`

```py
from django.contrib.auth import get_user_model
from django.contrib.auth.backends import ModelBackend


class EmailAuthBackend(ModelBackend):

    def authenticate(self, request, email=None, password=None, **kwargs):
        UserModel = get_user_model()
        if email is None:
            email = kwargs.get(UserModel.USERNAME_FIELD)
        if email is None or password is None:
            return
        try:
            user = UserModel._default_manager.get_by_natural_key(email)
        except UserModel.DoesNotExist:
            # Run the default password hasher once to reduce the timing
            # difference between an existing and a nonexistent user (#20760).
            UserModel().set_password(password)
        else:
            if user.check_password(password) and self.user_can_authenticate(user):
                return user
```

`./accounts/models.py`

```py
from django.db import models
from django.contrib.auth.models import AbstractBaseUser, BaseUserManager

class AccountManager(BaseUserManager):

    def create_user(self, email, password=None):

        if not email:
            raise ValueError("User must register with email.")

        user = self.model(
            email = self.normalize_email(email),
        )

        user.set_password(password)
        user.save(using=self.db)
        return user

    def create_superuser(self, email, password):

        user = self.create_user(
            email = self.normalize_email(email),
            password = password,
        )

        user.is_staff = True
        user.is_admin = True
        user.is_superuser = True
        user.save(using=self.db)
        return user


class Account(AbstractBaseUser):

    email = models.EmailField(unique=True)
    date_joined = models.DateTimeField(auto_now_add=True)
    last_login = models.DateTimeField(auto_now=True)
    is_staff = models.BooleanField(default=False)
    is_admin = models.BooleanField(default=False)
    is_activate = models.BooleanField(default=True)
    is_superuser = models.BooleanField(default=False)

    objects = AccountManager()

    USERNAME_FIELD = 'email'

    def __str__(self):
        return self.email

    def has_perm(self, perm, obj=None):
        return self.is_admin

    def has_module_perms(self, app_label):
        return True
```

`./accounts/views.py`

```py
from django.views.generic import TemplateView
from django.shortcuts import render, redirect
from django.contrib.auth import login, logout, authenticate

from .forms import RegisterationForm, LogInForm


class HomePageView(TemplateView):

    template_name = 'index.html'


def RegisterView(request):

    user = request.user
    if user.is_authenticated:
        return redirect('home')

    context = {}
    if request.POST:
        form = RegisterationForm(request.POST)
        if form.is_valid():
            user = form.save()
            login(request, user, backend='accounts.backends.EmailAuthBackend')
            return redirect('home')
    else:
        form = RegisterationForm()

    context['register_form'] = form
    return render(request, 'accounts/register.html', context)

def LogInView(request):

    user = request.user
    if user.is_authenticated:
        return redirect('home')

    context = {}
    if request.POST:
        form = LogInForm(request.POST)
        if form.is_valid():
            email = request.POST['email']
            password = request.POST['password']
            user = authenticate(email=email, password=password)
            if user:
                login(request, user, backend='accounts.backends.EmailAuthBackend')
                return redirect('home')

    else:
        form = LogInForm()

    context['login_form'] = form
    return render(request, "accounts/login.html", context)


def LogOutView(request):
    logout(request)
    return redirect('home')
```

`./accounts/forms.py`

```py
from django import forms
from django.contrib.auth.forms import UserCreationForm
from django.contrib.auth import authenticate

from .models import Account

class RegisterationForm(UserCreationForm):

    email = forms.EmailField(label='email', error_messages={
                                                              'invalid': 'Email Invaild',
                                                              'required':'Enter email please.'
                                                              })

    password1 = forms.EmailField(error_messages={'required':'Enter password please.'})
    password2 = forms.EmailField(error_messages={'required':'Enter password confirmation please.'})

    error_messages = {
        'password_mismatch': ('Two passwords did not match.'),
    }

    class Meta:

        model = Account
        fields = ('email', 'password1', 'password2')

    def clean_email(self):

        email = self.cleaned_data['email']
        try:
            account = Account.objects.get(email=email)
        except Exception as e:
            return email
        raise forms.ValidationError(f'{email} has been registered.')


class LogInForm(forms.ModelForm):

    email = forms.EmailField(error_messages={'required':'Enter email.'})
    password = forms.CharField(error_messages={'required':'Enter password.'})

    class Meta:
        model = Account
        fields = ('email', 'password')

    def clean(self):
        if self.is_valid():
            email = self.cleaned_data['email']
            password = self.cleaned_data['password']
            if not authenticate(email=email, password=password):
                raise forms.ValidationError("Login Fail!")
```

I also use customize password validators.

`./accounts/validators.py`

```py
from django.core.exceptions import ValidationError
from django.utils.translation import ugettext as _

class CustomizePasswordValidator():

    def __init__(self, min_length=8):
        self.min_length = min_length

    def validate(self, password, user=None):

        special_characters = "[~\!@#\$%\^&\*\(\)_\+{}\":;'\[\]]"

        if ( len(password) < 8 ) \
        or ( password.isalpha() ) \
        or ( password.isnumeric() ) \
        or ( password in special_characters) :
            raise ValidationError(_('Please enter more than 8 nums and alphabet combination.'))

    def get_help_text(self):
        return ""
```

`./confif/settings.py`

```py
import os

# Build paths inside the project like this: os.path.join(BASE_DIR, ...)
BASE_DIR = os.path.dirname(os.path.dirname(os.path.abspath(__file__)))


# Quick-start development settings - unsuitable for production
# See https://docs.djangoproject.com/en/2.0/howto/deployment/checklist/

# SECURITY WARNING: keep the secret key used in production secret!


# SECURITY WARNING: don't run with debug turned on in production!
DEBUG = True

ALLOWED_HOSTS = []


# Application definition

INSTALLED_APPS = [
    'django.contrib.admin',
    'django.contrib.auth',
    'django.contrib.contenttypes',
    'django.contrib.sessions',
    'django.contrib.messages',
    'django.contrib.staticfiles',

    'accounts',
]

MIDDLEWARE = [
    'django.middleware.security.SecurityMiddleware',
    'django.contrib.sessions.middleware.SessionMiddleware',
    'django.middleware.common.CommonMiddleware',
    'django.middleware.csrf.CsrfViewMiddleware',
    'django.contrib.auth.middleware.AuthenticationMiddleware',
    'django.contrib.messages.middleware.MessageMiddleware',
    'django.middleware.clickjacking.XFrameOptionsMiddleware',
]

ROOT_URLCONF = 'config.urls'

TEMPLATES = [
    {
        'BACKEND': 'django.template.backends.django.DjangoTemplates',
        'DIRS': [ os.path.join(BASE_DIR, 'templates').replace('\\', '/') ],
        'APP_DIRS': True,
        'OPTIONS': {
            'context_processors': [
                'django.template.context_processors.debug',
                'django.template.context_processors.request',
                'django.contrib.auth.context_processors.auth',
                'django.contrib.messages.context_processors.messages',
            ],
        },
    },
]

WSGI_APPLICATION = 'config.wsgi.application'


# Database
# https://docs.djangoproject.com/en/2.0/ref/settings/#databases

DATABASES = {
    'default': {
        'ENGINE': 'django.db.backends.sqlite3',
        'NAME': os.path.join(BASE_DIR, 'db.sqlite3'),
    }
}


# Password validation
# https://docs.djangoproject.com/en/2.0/ref/settings/#auth-password-validators

AUTH_PASSWORD_VALIDATORS = [
    #{
    #    'NAME': 'django.contrib.auth.password_validation.UserAttributeSimilarityValidator',
    #},
    #{
    #    'NAME': 'django.contrib.auth.password_validation.MinimumLengthValidator',
    #},
    #{
    #    'NAME': 'django.contrib.auth.password_validation.CommonPasswordValidator',
    #},
    #{
    #    'NAME': 'django.contrib.auth.password_validation.NumericPasswordValidator',
    #},
    {
        'NAME': 'accounts.validators.CustomizePasswordValidator',
    },
]


# Internationalization
# https://docs.djangoproject.com/en/2.0/topics/i18n/

LANGUAGE_CODE = 'en-us'

TIME_ZONE = 'UTC'

USE_I18N = True

USE_L10N = True

USE_TZ = True


# Static files (CSS, JavaScript, Images)
# https://docs.djangoproject.com/en/2.0/howto/static-files/

STATIC_URL = '/static/'
STATICFILES_DIRS = [
                    os.path.join(BASE_DIR, "static"),
                    ]


AUTH_USER_MODEL = 'accounts.Account'
AUTHENTICATION_BACKENDS = (
    'django.contrib.auth.backends.AllowAllUsersModelBackend',
    'accounts.backends.EmailAuthBackend',
    )
```

Did anyone face a similar situation before?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Your admin class `AccountAdmin` inherits from `UserAdmin`. If you check it's implementation it sets `add_form = UserCreationForm`, which has the following [line [Github code]](https://github.com/django/django/blob/a464ead29db8bf6a27a5291cad9eb3f0f3f0472b/django/contrib/auth/admin.py#L59) in it's `Meta` class: `fields = ("username",)`.

Since you already have made a custom form inheriting from `UserCreationForm` you should set that in your admin class:

```
from .forms import RegisterationForm


class AccountAdmin(UserAdmin):
    ...
    #              Remove ↓
    readonly_fields = ('email', 'date_joined', 'last_login')
    ...
    add_form = RegisterationForm
```

Comment: I tried, but it doesn't work. Email field of admin page Account model 'add' function still disable.

Comment: My Login Form used to work before I deleted db.sqlite3, but now it shows  'Enter a valid email address.'  message for the email used to be vaild. Does these two things related?

Comment: @PeterYang why have you put `email` in `readonly_fields`? all the fields in `readonly_fields` are passed as the `exclude` option to the form built by the model admin due to which your email field is not showing up.

Comment: OMG, there it is. I didn't notice that. Thanks a lot.